# Getting rid of white space at the bottom right of a footer

Tags: html, css, space

I'm trying to get rid of a bar of white space at the bottom of my footer. Here is the HTML:

```
        <hr style="height:7px; color:ff6c00; background-color: ff6c00; margin:-10; border:2px solid ff6c00;"/>

        <p><center><font family=audiowide size=20px color=white> Money  <font color=ff6c00>&bull;</font>  Time <font color=ff6c00>&bull;</font>  Health</font></center></p>

    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.Footer {
    background:#666666;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  word-spacing : 2em;
}
```

I had the same problem with my header, but I used    `"display:inline"` to fix it, that does not seem to work here as I'm not nesting divs as I did on my header.

Edit: the white space is ONLY at the bottom right corner of the footer, not all edges, which is the problem I solved with `"display:inline"`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the footer supposed to look like?

Comment: It is supposed to span the width of the bottom of the page, its dark grey with white text.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your .Footer css rule with this

```
.Footer {
    background:#666666;
    text-align:left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: This seems to mangle the footer completely, I had this same issue with position:absolute when trying to figure it out on my own.